Plugin Action to Expanded View on iOS Mobile Doesn't Scroll
Should content in the Expanded View be able to scroll, regardless of how the view is launched?
When a website is launched from the Card's Primary Action Button with Express code:
res.redirect('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page');

...the content shown cannot be scrolled on iOS (3.11.2), but it can on Android (3.11.1).
Here is a screencap showing the same actions side-by-side in iOS (right) and Android (left) using this code for the iframe:

Scrolling works in the expanded view on iOS when the link is opened with anchor tags and @jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge.
Scrolling does not work on iOS when the primary action button is used to open the link.


The Expanded View should be able to scroll, no matter if you're activating the Expanded View from the Card Face via a primary action button or the Plugin Bridge. Both cases should be identical in terms of scrolling capability within the Expanded View. A couple of questions to help clarify things below.


You mentioned that the scrolling works as expected when activating the Expanded View from a primary action button on Android. However, you're encountering issues on iOS. The natural question is, are you using the latest version of the iOS app? As of this writing, that's 3.11.2.



Ideally, you would be able to reproduce the problem in one of our example projects: simple-plugin-example or basic-plugin-example ..then edit your question with the relevant code attached. (Probably a good way to do so would be to have a public fork which includes your modifications, then highlight/summarize the changes in the text of the question.)


Thanks for the reply @JaimeLopezJr. - I updated the question with a screencap and a repo with the code used.  I seem to have the latest version - and this issue occurs reliably in our setup.

This does seem reproducible (and unexpected) - I alerted the product team to take a look. We'll report back any findings from that.

The team identified the issue and should be fixed in the 3.12 release. Thanks for pointing this out!

Following up, it looks like this fixed in 3.11.3 (so a bit earlier in terms of version).
